# How to set HDD to read and write

Tags: hard-drive, storage

I have installed a HDD on a second SATA port. But it is set to read-only. How do I set in to read and write?

It also somehow copied everything from my main SSD. I can access it but I can't write to it or format it.

I am using Windows 7.

If I go to the computer > manage in storage > diskstorage the HDD shows up under port1 (port0 is main SSD) but instead of "online" it says "write-only".

Note: there is nothing important on the HDD that has to be preserved.

Comment: More details would be super helpful. What OS? What do you mean by "read only"? What sorts of errors are you getting?

Comment: Frankly it sounds like you have a deeper problem. Copying everything from your main hard drive to the new drive couldn't have happened instantly. It sounds as if the machine is somehow looking at your original drive even when you try to browse the new one.

Comment: 1st sentence "read-only" vs. 4th paragraph "write-only"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The disk was somehow set to recovery. therefore the computer made a copy of the SSD and wrote it to the HDD. The solution was to set the HDD to non-raid. I did it by using the Intel rapid sorage technology.